# Tizen Web doesn't support CDN?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tizen

So I'm developing an app on gear s2 (Tizen) which involves maps. I added the necessary

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=true">
```

tag for google maps and the

```
<div id="main-map"></div>
```

associated with the map as is normally done with a web app. When running the app, it says:

> ReferenceError: can't find "google" object

although this is the same way I develop on Ionic's framework or a normal website and it works perfectly. To verify whether this is a problem with Google Maps, I used Here Maps and the same problem occurs. Then I checked with an ordinary CDN like jQuery and it didn't work as well while a local jQuery library works!

Please advise me for a solution for this issue.

Comment: The `sensor` parameter isn't required any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally!!

The solution is very simple. You'll have to add privileges in `config.xml`. The following lines should be added:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet" />
<access origin="http://googleapis.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://gstatic.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://google.com" subdomains="true" />
```

Hope this helps :)